# How to load and draw emojis on canvas efficiently?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, emoji

I would like to print an emoji on html canvas.

It can be done using images, but it is cumbersome. Is there a better way?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const contex = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "emoji.jpg";
img.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
  }
);
img.src = "img.jpg";
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### Edit:

Okey, I think my question is misunderstood. I am able to draw emoji as an image on canvas. I don't want to do that. Because I have to screenshot all the emojis and crop them before printing them on canvas, which is cumbersome. I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: So does your code works or not? You can use some custom fonts that places glyphs as emoji, e.g.: https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/ but it sill uses images

Comment: You may take a look at this pen: [Emo Bounce Boogie](https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/MvKbQz?editors=1010)

Comment: @Justinas My code works. I am looking for a better way.

Comment: I added a new solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) to draw the unicode emoji.

You can copy and paste the emojis from [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/).

I'm certainly not an expert on this so I don't know if there's big drawbacks to doing it this way, but here are some things to consider regardless.

1. This might not work on all browsers / operating systems.
2. The standard emoji will likely look different between browsers/systems unless you use a custom font
3. You should make sure your js is being read as UTF-8 for this to work. This is standard with HTML5, so you probably don't have to change anything unless it doesn't work for you.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const contex = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The size of the emoji is set with the font
contex.font = '100px serif'
// use these alignment properties for "better" positioning
contex.textAlign = "center"; 
contex.textBaseline = "middle"; 
// draw the emoji
contex.fillText('', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need another kind of approach. First, when we use the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` method we need: *i*) to load an image then we will modify the image and draw it onto the canvas, therefore, we also need *ii*) to resize the canvas. What about if we just use the **emojis** provided by [Unicode emoji characters](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

This example will help us to use an emoji via its `codepoint` value. We just need to pass a `hexcode` through the `String.fromCodePoint` method. This method returns a `string` created by using the specified sequence of code points. Then we can print that string into the canvas as an emoji. This approach will save a lot of time chopping, resizing and rendering each emoji. Check out this short example:

```js
const emojis = [
  0x1F600, 0x1F601, 0x1F603, 0x1F603, 0x1F604, 0x1F605, 0x1F606,
  0x1F607, 0x1F609, 0x1F60A, 0x1F642, 0x1F643, 0x1F355, 0x1F354,
]

const emoji = []
const size = 80
const factor = 2
const placeholder = document.getElementById('emojis')

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  emoji.push({
    x: size,
    y: size,
    src: getEmoji()
  });
}

function loadCanvas(id, emo) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.id = id
  placeholder.appendChild(canvas)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  loadEmoji(canvas, ctx, emo)
}


function loadEmoji(canvas, ctx, emo) {
  // Use the intrinsic size of image in CSS pixels for the canvas element
  canvas.width = w = size * factor
  canvas.height = h = size * factor

  const fontSize = size * (factor - .5)
  const offset = Math.floor((h - fontSize) / 4)

  ctx.font = `${size * (factor - .5)}px Arial`
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
  ctx.textAlign = 'center'

  emo.x = w / 2
  emo.y = h - size + offset

  ctx.fillText(emo.src, emo.x, emo.y)
}

function getEmoji() {
  const len = emojis.length
  const emos = Math.floor(Math.random() * len)

  return String.fromCodePoint(emojis[emos])
}


window.onload = function() {
  emoji.forEach((emo, i) => {
    const id = `canvas-0${i}`
    loadCanvas(id, emo)
  })
}
```

```css
#emojis {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#emojis * {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="emojis"></div>
```

#### Note

Remember that this might not work on all browsers and the emojis will change according to the operating system where it's been displayed.

Comment: Nice! .. but why the "factor"?

Comment: factor helps to align the emotion in the inline, what we are trying to emulate here is a typography, where the emotion is the x-height and the red area is the font-height. So the factor helps to center the emoticon inside the red area.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use images then I have an example here that is pure coding. As you can see it requires way more coding tho.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Smiley Face</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smiley.css" >

</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="600" height="600" id="smiley">
        <p>You need canvas!</p>
        <p>This example requires a browser that supports the
        <a href="http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/">HTML5</a> 
        &lt;canvas&gt; feature.</p>
    </canvas>
    <script src="js/smiley.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

smiley.js

```
//smileyView Object literal
class smileyComponent {
  constructor() {
    //initialise window, cv & ctx, drawSmiley & call drawsmiley
    this._window = this;
    this._cv = document.getElementById('smiley');
    this._ctx = this._cv.getContext('2d');
    this.drawSmiley();
  }
  //getters
  get window() {
    return this._window;
  }
  get cv() {
    return this._cv;
  }
  get ctx() {
    return this._ctx;
  }

  drawArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise) {
    this._ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise);
  }
  drawLine(xs, ys, xe, ye) {
    this._ctx.moveTo(xs, ys);
    this._ctx.lineTo(xe, ye);
  }
  drawSmiley() {
    //initialise lineWidth & fillStyle
    this._ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    this._ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    this._ctx.lineWidth = 5;

    //head
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(300,300,200,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(0),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(360),true);
    this._ctx.fill();

    //left eye
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(200,200,50,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(0),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(360),true);
    this._ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    this._ctx.fill();
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(220,220,25,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(0),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(360),true);
    this._ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this._ctx.fill();


    //right eye
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(400,200,50,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(0),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(360),true);
    this._ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    this._ctx.fill();
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(420,220,25,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(0),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(360),true);
    this._ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    this._ctx.fill();

    //nose
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawLine(300,350,300,250);
    this._ctx.stroke();


    //smile
    this._ctx.beginPath();
    this.drawArc(300,300,150,smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(160),smileyComponent.degreesToRadians(380),true);
    this._ctx.stroke();
  }

  static degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}
window.onload = () => new smileyComponent();
```

You can check the result [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/zOw7kgwpYNZ4).

Comment: Why does this have redundant getters? You could just remove the underscores from the attribute names.

Comment: Copied this from an existing project, but you're right