# How to draw all emojis using p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm try to draw emoji on p5.js canvas.
But on windows platform, some emoji are displayed only them outline.(e.g. ☀)
When I using, I could display on html element but couldn't on p5.js canvas.
Is there good and simple method for displaying emojis correctly on windows?

Comment: Use a font that handles emojis like you want instead of the default font.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried or a link to a *new* p5 editor sketch with just the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or preferably both.

Comment: I wanna to use WebFont for p5.js, but I can't find how to do it. I could do on html by referenced https://codepen.io/suin/pen/ryrELN .

Answer (score 4):

[Live Code Example](https://editor.p5js.org/Samathingamajig/sketches/KQXCnCHcO)

Make sure you actually use the emoji correctly, the easiest way is to copy [from Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/). (You can also type these emojis by pressing and holding the Windows Key + . (period) if on Windows))

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  textSize(64);
  textAlign(CENTER)
  text('', width/2, height/2);
  text('☀️️', width/2, height/2 + 100);
}
```

Remember, under the hood, the p5.js library is just that: a library. This meaning it can easily be converted to normal javascript, so you can search up how to draw emojis in the html `<canvas>`, and you find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312457/how-to-load-and-draw-emojis-on-canvas-efficiently/56312911). This shouldn't be marked as duplicate, though, because p5js has different commands to display this compared to just using `ctx.`.

Comment: Hi @samathinganajig ! Thanks for the example. I happened to walk through this post and working on my own project involve text and font! So what font that makes this emoji possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure emojis are determined by your operating system, (or an image/svg on some websites showing examples of emojis) not a specific font @TeeTee